# Очень много ошибок, я из файла ui создал файл py и в этом файле вот что

Tags: python, pyqt5, ui, pyside2

Ошибки в первых двух from что нет такого имени в модуле PySide2
Одна из них - "No name 'QCoreApplication' in module 'PySide2.QtCore'"

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        if mainWindow.objectName():
            mainWindow.setObjectName(u"mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(364, 483)
        mainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"max-height: 483px;\n"
"max-width: 364px;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"background-color: #FFCB8B;\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(u"Generate__btn:pressed {\n"
"   background-color: #FFCB8B;\n"
"}")
        self.Title = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setObjectName(u"Title")
        self.Title.setGeometry(QRect(110, 10, 131, 51))
        self.Title.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #FFC46B;\n"
"font-size: 20px;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Min__label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Min__label.setObjectName(u"Min__label")
        self.Min__label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 120, 101, 41))
        self.Min__label.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"background-color: #FFAF50;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Max__label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Max__label.setObjectName(u"Max__label")
        self.Max__label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 180, 111, 41))
        self.Max__label.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"background-color: #FC9A40;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Min__input = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Min__input.setObjectName(u"Min__input")
        self.Min__input.setGeometry(QRect(140, 130, 201, 31))
        self.Min__input.setStyleSheet(u"color: gray;\n"
"background-color: #FF905A;\n"
"padding: 5px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.Max__input = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Max__input.setObjectName(u"Max__input")
        self.Max__input.setGeometry(QRect(140, 190, 201, 31))
        self.Max__input.setStyleSheet(u"color: gray;\n"
"background-color: #FFAD32;\n"
"padding: 5px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.Generate__btn = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Generate__btn.setObjectName(u"Generate__btn")
        self.Generate__btn.setGeometry(QRect(110, 280, 121, 41))
        self.Generate__btn.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.Generate__btn.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: #DF8600;\n"
"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"")
        self.Result = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result.setObjectName(u"Result")
        self.Result.setGeometry(QRect(70, 370, 201, 51))
        self.Result.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"padding: 10px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"border: 2px solid black;")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 364, 21))
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Randomizer", None))
        self.Title.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Randomizer", None))
        self.Min__label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Minimum:", None))
        self.Max__label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Maximum:", None))
        self.Min__input.setText("")
        self.Max__input.setText("")
        self.Generate__btn.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Generate", None))
        self.Result.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Result", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 2):

Я не могу сказать про `'PySide2`, так как имею `PyQt5` и там все работает.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient,  
    QCursor)                                                                   # +++
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,               # +++
    QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QMenuBar, QStatusBar)

class Ui_mainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        if mainWindow.objectName():
            mainWindow.setObjectName(u"mainWindow")
        mainWindow.resize(364, 483)
        mainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"max-height: 483px;\n"
"max-width: 364px;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"background-color: #FFCB8B;\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(mainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet(u"Generate__btn:pressed {\n"
"   background-color: #FFCB8B;\n"
"}")
        self.Title = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setObjectName(u"Title")
        self.Title.setGeometry(QRect(110, 10, 131, 51))
        self.Title.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"background-color: #FFC46B;\n"
"font-size: 20px;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Min__label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Min__label.setObjectName(u"Min__label")
        self.Min__label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 120, 101, 41))
        self.Min__label.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"background-color: #FFAF50;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Max__label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Max__label.setObjectName(u"Max__label")
        self.Max__label.setGeometry(QRect(20, 180, 111, 41))
        self.Max__label.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"background-color: #FC9A40;\n"
"padding: 10px;")
        self.Min__input = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Min__input.setObjectName(u"Min__input")
        self.Min__input.setGeometry(QRect(140, 130, 201, 31))
        self.Min__input.setStyleSheet(u"color: gray;\n"
"background-color: #FF905A;\n"
"padding: 5px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.Max__input = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Max__input.setObjectName(u"Max__input")
        self.Max__input.setGeometry(QRect(140, 190, 201, 31))
        self.Max__input.setStyleSheet(u"color: gray;\n"
"background-color: #FFAD32;\n"
"padding: 5px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.Generate__btn = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Generate__btn.setObjectName(u"Generate__btn")
        self.Generate__btn.setGeometry(QRect(110, 280, 121, 41))
        self.Generate__btn.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.Generate__btn.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: #DF8600;\n"
"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"border: none;\n"
"outline: none;\n"
"")
        self.Result = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Result.setObjectName(u"Result")
        self.Result.setGeometry(QRect(70, 370, 201, 51))
        self.Result.setStyleSheet(u"color: black;\n"
"padding: 10px;\n"
"font-size: 18px;\n"
"text-align: center;\n"
"border: 2px solid black;")
        mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(mainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 364, 21))
        mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(mainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
        mainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Randomizer", None))
        self.Title.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Randomizer", None))
        self.Min__label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Minimum:", None))
        self.Max__label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Maximum:", None))
        self.Min__input.setText("")
        self.Max__input.setText("")
        self.Generate__btn.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Generate", None))
        self.Result.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("mainWindow", u"Result", None))
    # retranslateUi


class ExampleApp(QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скажите, какой ваш родной язык?) всегда было интересно..

Comment: Скажите какой командой компилировали?